# Why is real time more than user+system+total?

Tags: ruby, benchmarking

I ran a benchmark test doing random things to see how much time these things take:

```
                              user     system      total        real
joining an array of strings  0.040000   0.010000   0.050000 (  0.046636)
string interpolation         0.020000   0.000000   0.020000 (  0.023903)
just timing                  0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.004334)
```

I guess that the real time can be less than the total time, given I have a multicore processor, but in the last case only real time is reported with others being 0. I don't get how that could be the case.

If it's relevant, these are my benchmarking tests:

```
require 'benchmark'

iterations = 10_000

Benchmark.bm do |bm|
  bm.report('joining an array of strings') do
    iterations.times do
      ["The","Current","Time","Is",Time.now].join(" ")
    end
  end

  bm.report('string interpolation') do
    iterations.times do
      "The current time is #{Time.now}"
    end
  end

  bm.report('just timing') do
    iterations.times do
      Time.now
    end
  end

end
```

Edit: So I bump up my `iterations` to `iterations = 1_000_000` and these are the new results:

```
                               user     system      total        real
joining an array of strings  3.640000   0.000000   3.640000 (  3.644826)
string interpolation         2.390000   0.000000   2.390000 (  2.393069)
just timing                  0.390000   0.000000   0.390000 (  0.392369)
```

The real time still appears to be more than total time, and I still don't get that even if the time being taken by the last test was below resolution then real time should also have been 0 which was not the case.

Comment: increase `iterations` until "just timing" has a value. You're below the resolution of the timer right now. Or, use the [Fruity](https://github.com/marcandre/fruity) gem which will do those things for you.

Comment: So the timer for user/system/total and real have different resolutions?

Comment: They should be the same resolution, it's just that it takes a lot less time to return `Time.now` so you have to increase the number of iterations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A process can be in the blocking wait state, mostly while waiting for IO. In this time the process is not on the CPU so no CPU time is counted.

Another reason for a larger difference between total and system+user is a system which such a high load, the processes get on and off CPU very frequently.